# JavaScript Regex not replacing as expected

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I have this function in PHP:

```
function sanitizeKey($str){
  $str = strtolower($str);
  $str = preg_replace('/[^\da-z ]/i', '', trim(ucwords($str)));
  $str = str_replace(" ", "", $str);
  $str = lcfirst($str);
  return $str;
}
```

When run against `Manufacture's  P/N` the output is `manufacturesPn`.

I'm rewriting the same function in Javascript and so far have this code:

```
str = "Manufacture's  P/N";

str = str.toLowerCase()
  .replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function(letter) { // php's ucwords
    return letter.toUpperCase();
  });
str = str.trim(); // remove leading & trailing whitespace
str = str.replace("/[^\da-z ]/i", ''); // keep alphanumeric
str = str.replace(/\s+/g, ''); // remove whitespace
str = str.replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function(letter) { // php's lcfirst
  return letter.toLowerCase();
});

console.log(str);
```

At this point if I input `Manufacture's  P/N` the current output is `Manufacture'SP/N`.

**Question**
How do I change my JavaScript code to replicate the PHP program so it produces the same output for the same input?

Comment: @whoever If you downvote, please be so kind to explain why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```js
str = "Manufacture's  P/N";
    
console.log(
str.trim()
.toLowerCase()
.replace(/[^\da-z ]+/gi, '')
.replace(/(?!^)\b[a-z]/g, function(c) {
   return c.toUpperCase(); 
})
.replace(/\s+/g, '')
)
    
//=> "manufacturesPn"
```

In Javascript you shouldn't quote regex e.g. `"/[^\da-z ]/i"` and use global flag to replace globally.

Comment: Aaah! Thanks so much, I was waiting for the explaination.

Comment: `(?^)` is negative lookahead to skip starting character becoming uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

You can match every character use `.test()`, `.indexOf()` within `.replace()` function

```js
var str = "Manufacture's  P/N";

var res = str.replace(/./g, function(p) {      
  return /[a-z]/i.test(p) && !/\s/.test(str[str.indexOf(p) - 1]) 
         ? p.toLowerCase() : /['/ ]/.test(p) ? "" : p
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
str = "Manufacture's  P/N";

str = $.trim(str).split("  ");
str1 = str[0].toLowerCase().replace("'", '');
str2 = str[1].toLowerCase().replace("/", '');
str3 = str2.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str2.slice(1);
finalString = str1 + str3;

return finalString;

console.log(finalString);
```